# Best way to compute matrix quadratic form in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

Given a `Vector` denoted `v` and `Matrix` denoted `M`, what is the fastest method for computing the matrix quadratic form in Julia, i.e. `v'Mv`? What about the most elegant?

**Note:** I would like the return value to be a scalar. Interestingly, if `v = rand(3)` and `M = rand(3, 3)`, then `v'*M*v` returns a vector containing one element, not a scalar. I was not expecting this behaviour, although have read enough github issue pages to suspect there is a good reason for this behaviour that I'm just not smart enough to see. So, obviously `(v'*M*v)[1]` will do the job, just wondering if there is a better method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option that returns a scalar is `dot(v, M*v)`.

Comment: Efficient and elegant. Just the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You can also use the `⋅` operator for visual recognition: `v⋅M*v` (see math/latex/unicode input for your editor eg: [emacs](https://github.com/vspinu/company-math))

Comment: I should mention that this can be done with `dot(v, M, v)` since Julia 1.4.

Answer (score 3):

How about a double `for`? Would save allocations of intermediate vector.
For completeness, in code:

```
vMv{T}(v::Vector{T},M::Matrix{T}) = begin
    size(M) == (size(v,1),size(v,1)) || throw("Vector/Matrix size mismatch")
    res = zero(T)
    for i = 1:size(v,1)
        for j = 1:size(v,1)
            res += v[i]*v[j]*M[i,j]
        end
    end
    res
end
```

Adding some `@inbounds` and perhaps `@simd`s would optimize.

Comment: For special vector and matrices (i.e. sparse), using regular matrix multiplication and dot product might take advantage of faster functions. See David P. Sanders' option.

Comment: I believe that `dot` and `*` will use fast optimized BLAS routines.

Comment: True. Benchmarks would decide best, as there is still the allocation issue with `dot(...)`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do like the avoidance of temporary arrays in your answer, but would be a bit worried about not taking advantage of `dot` and `gemv` in `Base.LinAlg.BLAS`, so I've marked David's response as the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean about the allocation, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: I guess if it's a quadratic form then M is probably a symmetric matrix, which further complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to point out that `n(n-1)/2` operations are redundant in the above double loop; if `v` is a vector on n elements and `M` is a nxn matrix, the computation of quadratic form v'Mv requires the following operations only:

`sum_i=1:n(v[i]^2 * M[i, i]) + sum_j=1:n-1, i=j+1:n(2 * (v[i] * v[j] * M[i, j]))`